# Creating a variable that illustrate change in another variable

Tags: r, variables, dummy-variable

I'm trying to create a variable that illustrate change in dicthomous variable.
In other words, I have a dummy variable that illustrate whether something is active during a specific year. I need the new variable to account for change in the dummy variable while accounting for year and country. I have tried to illustrate the dummy I'm trying to create in the variable `NewChangeVariable` below.

```
read.table(
text =
"Country, Year, Dummy, NewChangeVariable,
US, 1, 1, 0,
US, 2, 0, 0,
US, 3, 1, 1,
US, 4, 1, 0,
UK, 1, 0, 0,
UK, 2, 1, 1, 
UK, 3, 1, 0, 
UK, 4, 1, 0, ", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

The `NewChangeVariable` is suppose to react to the first year a positive change in the `dummy` takes places. Again, dependent on country.

Please dont hesitate to ask if anything is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse approach. First, you can `group_by` `Country`. Then, for each `Country`, get the first row number where the prior `Dummy` was 0, but that row's `Dummy` is 1. Those rows meeting the criteria will be set to 1 (otherwise 0).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(NewChangeVariable2 = +(row_number() == which(lag(Dummy) == 0 & Dummy == 1)[1]))
```

**Output**

```
  Country  Year Dummy NewChangeVariable NewChangeVariable2
  <chr>   <int> <int>             <dbl>              <int>
1 US          1     1                 0                  0
2 US          2     0                 0                  0
3 US          3     1                 1                  1
4 US          4     1                 0                  0
5 UK          1     0                 0                  0
6 UK          2     1                 1                  1
7 UK          3     1                 0                  0
8 UK          4     1                 0                  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can see I have made an mistake in the df illustrated there that doesn't corresponds to my original data, I have left out 'NA' values (that is 'NA' in the Dummy-variable). Sadly, when I apply this code to the real dataset the NewChangeVariable2 takes the value 'NA' in all observation, how do I account for this?

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the comment - would it be possible to edit your original post and include data that is more representative of your original data? And include some missing `NA` dummy values? Then I can adjust the code accordingly so that it works in those situations. Thanks!

Comment: @Jens This might help clarify what are "positive changes" - the code above looks for one row of 0 followed by another row of 1 - do you have situations of missing values between 0 and 1, which would constitute a "positive change"? I think a more detailed example will help in understanding this, perhaps with different situations.